# Adding user profile picture in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I've recently started programming in Kotlin and cannot seem to add a profile picture to a user when registering it.
According to the code here, I can access to the gallery and retrieve the image information. The picture will appear on screen, but after registering the user the image url will not appear anywhere.

```
class RegisterUser : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    private val auth: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    private val UserCreation = database.getReference("Usuarios")

    private val pickImage = 100
    private var imageUri: Uri? = null
    lateinit var imageView: ImageView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_user)


        Goback.setOnClickListener {
            val Gobackou = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(Gobackou)
        }


        RegisterConfirm.setOnClickListener {
            val SetUser = SetUser.text.toString()
            val SetPass = setPass.text.toString()
            val SetEmail = SetEmail.text.toString()
            



            if (SetUser.isEmpty() && SetPass.isEmpty() && SetEmail.isEmpty()) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Faltan Campos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                RegisterUserv2(SetEmail, SetPass, SetUser)
            }

        }

        selectPP.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
            intent.type = "image/*"
            startActivityForResult(intent, pickImage)
        }
    }
    var selectedPhotoUri: Uri? = null
    //guardar la foto de perfil
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == pickImage) {
            val selectedPhotoUri = data?.data
            val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, selectedPhotoUri)
            val bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable(bitmap)
            userimg.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable)
        }
    }

    private fun RegisterUserv2(email: String, password: String, user: String) {
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {

                uploadimage()

                UltrasaveUsuario(Usuarios(auth.currentUser!!.uid, user, password, email))
                val Gobackou = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(Gobackou)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Registro ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun UltrasaveUsuario(usuario: Usuarios) {

        val mensajeFirebase = UserCreation.push()
        usuario.id = mensajeFirebase.key ?: ""

        mensajeFirebase.setValue(usuario)
    }

    private fun uploadimage(imageurl: String){
        if (selectedPhotoUri == null) return
        val filename = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
       val ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/images/$filename/")

        ref.putFile(selectedPhotoUri!!)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
            ref.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener{


            }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using firebase I will show you how to save firebase storage.

```
private fun uploadImage() {
        if (mSelectedImageFileUri != null) {
            val sRef: StorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child(
                "users/ $uid/profile.jpg"
            )
            sRef.putFile(mSelectedImageFileUri!!)
                .addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
                    taskSnapshot.metadata!!.reference!!.downloadUrl
                        .addOnSuccessListener { url ->
                           
                        }
                }.addOnFailureListener {
                    //error
                }
        } else {
            
        }
    }
```

then you will take this picture using the user id to take .

firebase>storage to view the image

getImage

```
val sRef: StorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child(
                        "users/ $uid/profile.jpg"
                    )
                    sRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                        Picasso.get().load(it).into(globalprofileImage)
                    }
```

Build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNYLQcmB7AU&t=449s&ab_channel=SmallAcademy